# Need COM4j.jar file for QC12.21

Tags: java, jira-rest-api, hp-quality-center

I am using QC12.21 but i am unable to fing COM4J.jar file for QC12.21. When i am creating a connection with QC through JIra Rest API, it is giving me an incompatibility issue. If anyone have com4j.jar file for QC12.21, Please share here
Error-
The OTA version is not compatible with the current version of the Application Lifecycle Management server: http://qc12prod.corp.sopra:8080/qcbin/wcomsrv.dll.
OTA version: 12.21, OTA build number: 3825. Server version: 12.21, server build number: 4025

Comment: I can help you if you are stucked with QC rest api somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

There are **no** special com4j.jar files for different versions of HP ALM server. COM4j library is needed to generate wrapper for OTAClient.dll and use it in a runtime. 
And moreover, com4j.jar is not needed at all if you are going to communicate with HP ALM via REST API.
If you still want to use OTA to communicate with HP ALM - all you need is get OTAClient.dll from your server and generate wrapper classes using the latest version of COM4j.